# The page is not configured! [type= 0][]

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-4.5

I've migrated from typo3 4.1 to 4.5 LTS now I got this error.

```
The page is not configured! [type= 0][]
```

I've checked DB analyser and fixed the table issues any ideas. Please revert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently TYPO3 can't find TypoScript use Web > Template tool and check if record exists, also if it includes TS from external files, make sure the files exists.